# How to make a counter of values change by group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to make a counter that would change values only when it's different from the previous row or the ID I'm grouping by changes

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
ID Flag   New_Column
A   NaN     1
A   0       1
A   0       1
A   0       1
A   1       2
A   1       2
A   1       2
A   0       3
A   0       3
A   0       3
A   1       4
A   1       4
A   1       4
B   NaN     1
B   0       1
```

I want to create New_Column where every time the Flag values changes, I'd increment New_Column by one and if the ID changes, it would reset to one and start over

Here is what I tried to do using np.select but it's not working

```
df['New_Column'] = None
df['Flag_Lag'] = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Date_Time'], ascending=True).groupby(['ID'])['Flag'].shift(1)
df['ID_Lag'] = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Date_Time'], ascending=True).groupby(['ID'])['ID'].shift(1)


conditions = [((df['Flag'] != df['Flag_Lag']) & (df['ID'] == df['ID_Lag'])), 
              ((df['Flag'] == df['Flag_Lag']) & (df['ID'] == df['ID_Lag'])), 
              ((df['Flag_Lag'] == np.nan) & (df['New_Column'].shift(1) == 1)), 
              ((df['ID'] != df['ID_Lag']))
             ]

choices = [(df['New_Column'].shift(1) + 1), 
           (df['New_Column'].shift(1)), 
           (df['New_Column'].shift(1)), 
            1]

df['New_Column'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

With this code, the first value for New_Column is 1, the second is NaN and the rest is None

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: put source df as text

Comment: Changed df sample from image to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by ID and use cumulative sum of (current is not equal previous)

```
df['new'] =  df.groupby('ID') \ 
  apply(lambda x: x['Flag'].fillna(0).diff().ne(0).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

   ID  Flag  New_Column  new
0   A   NaN           1    1
1   A   0.0           1    1
2   A   0.0           1    1
3   A   0.0           1    1
4   A   1.0           2    2
5   A   1.0           2    2
6   A   1.0           2    2
7   A   0.0           3    3
8   A   0.0           3    3
9   A   0.0           3    3
10  A   1.0           4    4
11  A   1.0           4    4
12  A   1.0           4    4
13  B   NaN           1    1
14  B   0.0           1    1
```

Comment: What does the `reset_index` do?

Comment: if you want to know about the function -  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html  if you ask why it used it this code, i need to remembe

Answer (score 1):

If speed is not a concern and you want some easy-to-read code, you could simply iterate over the dataframe and run a simple function for each row.

```
def f(row):
    global previous_ID, previous_flag, previous_count

    if previous_ID == False: #let's start the count
        row['New_Column'] = 1

    elif previous_ID != row['ID']: #let's start the count over
        row['New_Column'] = 1

    elif previous_flag == row['Flag']: #same ID, same Flag
        row['New_Column'] = previous_count

    else: #same ID, different Flag
        row['New_Column'] = previous_count + 1


    previous_ID = row['ID']
    previous_flag = row['Flag']
    previous_count = row['New_Column']
```

You should fill your NaN values with a 0 probably or add a special case in the function for it.

You can run the function in the following way:

```
previous_ID, previous_flag, previous_count = False, False, False
df['New_Columns'] = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    f(row)
```

And that's it.